# How to use Extjs and jQuery drag and drop?

Tags: jquery, extjs, fullcalendar, extjs4.1

I have extjs grid with `gridviewdragdrop` plugin and with jquery UI `Droppable` div.

Maybe someone have tried write some kind of proxy between these two?

I am trying add event to `fullcalendar`(jquery plugin) by dragging from Extjs gridpanel.

Google wasn't so helpful. Now I am trying to look at source code of jquery droppable plugin and maybe I will find a way to fire dropped event or something but that's very unlikely.

Any advises are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make both the drag and the drop operations under 1 library/framework. By the sound of it, you're using ExtJS to drag the item - and jQuery to set a drop space. Try using jQuery to also perform the drag.

Comment: That would be great but how can I do that? jQuery doesn't know about gridpanel or records of grid.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to add events to a calendar, you may try [Ext.ensbile Calendar pro](http://ext.ensible.com/). They are built right on top of ExtJS and have decent documentation and examples.
You have to pay for commercial use though.

I have used it before for a scheduling use-case and was lot easier than trying to integrate with jQuery

Sorry - this is not an answer, but my reputation doesn't allow me to comment on the question yet :(

Comment: I found demo of drag and drop to this calendar but demo doesn't work. There is no easy way to make drag and drop to this calendar.